# How to upload a media item to WordPress from Delphi (Rio) app using TRestClient library

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, delphi, media

We have a WordPress developed site with a template that enables content management through WP's own support for REST API, and we want to upload content that has photos associated with it.
The idea is to upload the photos, and then upload the content associating it with the uploaded photos.
Our code for uploading photos is as follows (using the library usage example provided with the Delphi distribution):

```
procedure Tfrm_Main.btn_MediaClick(Sender: TObject);
var jpgFoto: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;

  RESTClient.BaseURL := lbledt_BaseWProp.Text;
  RESTClient.Authenticator := HTTPBasic_DelphiPRAXiS;

  RESTRequest.Resource := 'media';

  HTTPBasic_DelphiPRAXiS.Username := lbledt_Usuario.Text;
  HTTPBasic_DelphiPRAXiS.Password := lbledt_Clave.Text;

  jpgFoto := TMemoryStream.Create;
  jpgFoto.LoadFromFile('t:\beautiful-blowball-dandelion-vector-background.jpg');
  jpgFoto.Position := 0;
  RESTRequest.AddBody(jpgFoto, TRESTContentType.ctIMAGE_JPEG);
  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;

  RESTRequest.Execute;
  jpgFoto.Free;
end;
```

The response obtained is as follows:

```
{
    "code": "rest_upload_no_content_disposition",
    "message": "No se ha facilitado la disposición de contenido.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

We have not seen a clear example of how to do it and we are lost in the search for a solution.
Thank you!

Comment: A simple search gives [this](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2609).

Comment: I saw samples like that, but i can't figure how to made it works in delphi (sorry this is all new to me). Something like:
RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="media_test.jpg"')
Where media_test.jpd is target file name?

Comment: No, that's does not work... 

{
    "code": "rest_upload_invalid_disposition",
    "message": "La disposición de contenido facilitada no es válida. La disposición de contenido tiene que tener un formato como `attachment; filename=\"image.png\"` o similar.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a lot of alternatives... finally i am giving a try to Indy TidHTTP component. It seems to work fine! Thanks